# How to appraoch solving this series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, taylor-expansion, trigonometric-series

I am given the following series and asked to solve it.
$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-2)^n}{(2n+1)!}$
I recognize that this series is somewhat similar to the Taylor series for $sinx$ which is 
$\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$.

However, I am not really able to relate these two series in order to solve them, especially since my series starts at 1 and once I rewrite the $sinx$ series to match that, I am completely lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$\sin(x)-x
=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}
$,
$\dfrac{\sin(x)-x}{x}
=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty (-1)^n\dfrac{x^{2n}}{(2n+1)!}
=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-x^2)^{n}}{(2n+1)!}
$.

Therefore,
putting $\sqrt{x}$ for $x$,
$\dfrac{\sin(\sqrt{x})-\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}
=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{(-x)^{n}}{(2n+1)!}
$.

And there you are.

Comment: Subtract $1$ because the series actually starts at $n=1$, not $n=0$, so the first term of the expansion is ignored.

Comment: Oh wow. Thank you so much, makes it very clear.

Comment: @ Noble Mushtak: Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Shouldn't it be $sin(x)-x$ instead of $sinx-1$?? Because the first term is an x.

Comment: You are right. Thanks. I'm 0 for 2 today. Fixed.